# Notify fragment when it comes into view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to know when a user swipes in or out of fragments in my viewpager. I have managed to do it however the problem is that when the ViewPager is first created fragment 0 never knows it's visible.

I tried manually calling onPageSelected on MainActivity onCreate but it crashes my app.

How can I notify the first fragment it's visible as soon as it get's into view? it would be a plus if it were possible to notify the fragment only when it was fully visible (sometimes onPageSelected is called slightly before that)

```
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Listen for swipes
    final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            MiniApp fragment = (MiniApp) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager, position); 
            // Error
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.onFragmentEntered();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);

    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

How do I tell the fragment on the first screen it's visibile?

---

This is the error log:

```
04-11 20:56:23.697    3537-3537/com.example.android.launcher E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.launcher, PID: 3537
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.launcher/com.example.android.launcher.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
            at com.example.android.launcher.app.fragments.Clock.onFragmentEntered(Clock.java:54)
            at com.example.android.launcher.app.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:154)
            at com.example.android.launcher.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:137)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You're throwing a `NullPointerException` in your `Clock` `Fragment` on line `54` in `onFragmentEntered`. Can you post that line and any other relevant code pertaining to `onFragmentEntered`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually call `OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected`:

```
    final OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // When the page changes tell fragment visibility changed
            VisibilityChange fragment = (VisibilityChange) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(
                    mPager, position);

            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.onVisibilityChange(true);
            }
            fragment = (VisibilityChange) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager, lastPosition);
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.onVisibilityChange(false);
            }
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);
```

Comment: this seems to be a good idea, however I get an error when I try to tell the fragment the visibility changed. From my tests I think the reason is that the fragment is not already created on MainActivity onCreate. Actually it's not created after onStart and onResume so I'm not sure when to call `onPageSelected(0)` do you have any ideas? I started a little bounty, it shouldn't be hard to make it work from your solution

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could make it work. The problem was that the method onVisibilityChange() inside the fragment was using getActivity() and for some reason this crashed the app when calling onPageSelected() manually. Passing the context through onVisibilityChange() and using it instead of getActivity() fixed the issue. Do you know what might be the reason for this? (I need to wait 20hs to award the bounty)

Comment: @Liso22 Sounds like your `Fragment` hasn't been attached to your `Activity` by the time you're calling `Fragment.getActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 // Manages the Tab changes, synchronizing it with Pages
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) 
       {
        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.Drawable.XYZ); 
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
       }

    // Manages the Page changes, synchronizing it with Tabs
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override fragment's [`setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)). If `isVisibleToUser` is `true` then your fragment is visible in the pager.